# Error when creating a new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to create a new rails app.

When I enter "rails new app" to create it, this is what I see:

```
  create  
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/images/rails.png
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/mailers/.gitkeep
  create  app/models/.gitkeep
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  doc
  create  doc/README_FOR_APP
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.gitkeep
  create  log
  create  log/.gitkeep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/index.html
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  script
  create  script/rails
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
  create  test/functional
  create  test/functional/.gitkeep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.gitkeep
  create  test/unit
  create  test/unit/.gitkeep
  create  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
  create  vendor/plugins
  create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
     run  bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:54:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent/ssl_reuse.rb:70:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:750:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:628:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:570:in `connection_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/net/http/persistent.rb:930:in `request'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:195:in `fetch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:169:in `use_api'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `block in remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `select'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:223:in `remote_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:162:in `fetch_specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:66:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:189:in `block in index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/index.rb:9:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `index'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/definition.rb:109:in `resolve_remotely!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:14:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:247:in `install'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:4:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.3.0/bin/bundle:20:in `<main>'
        Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
        troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
unknown60c5479b0f80:apps martha$
```

What is this fatal error and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error is `SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)` and you can start looking into how to fix it at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues.

Comment: You can avoid to install the bundle directly with rails new app -B and fix it later on like @Amit Kumar Gupta said.